# Can I change Enum type from string to bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I am trying to send over sockets an Enum value, but however no matter what I try it gets encoded as a string (except when I manually convert it to bytes in the call to the socket.send)

```
class Example(Enum):
    A = b'example'
    B = bytes('example', 'utf8')
```

I call the send method from the socket module where sock is a prior bound socket for a server

```
....
conn, addr = sock.accept() 
conn.send(Example.A.name)
```

and the exception message is:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/enum.html) and some other links but I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Enum` is built on `OrderedDict`, so `name` corresponds to `key` and `value` is, well, `value`. Change to:

```py
Example.A.value
```

Which has a `bytes` type, unlike the `name` which has a string type (`A`)